# Crystal Reports- Section break after n records

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report document in visual studio 2008 and need to display a set of records from a single table. But after n records, I need to display some heading and then the remaining records to be displayed.

Example:

```
  1. What is your name?
  2. What is your age?

 Descriptive type questions

  3. How .....?
  4. what .....?
```

Please help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

If you know after which record number will be placed the heading info just create another details section under the one you already have and place the info there. Then do right clic go to that section expert and on suppress condition type `recordnumber <> n(your record number)`.
If you don't know the record number, but know the string will come before your heading, do the same thing using `instr(your field, "your string") = 0` instead. Both options are going to show your heading info only is that condition is false and then will continue with the remaining details.